# Duteronomy 17 applied today

Tags: beit-din-court, deuteronomy

Deuteronomy 17:8 says,

> כִּי יִפָּלֵא מִמְּךָ דָבָר לַמִּשְׁפָּט, בֵּין-דָּם לְדָם בֵּין-דִּין לְדִין וּבֵין נֶגַע לָנֶגַע--דִּבְרֵי רִיבֹת, בִּשְׁעָרֶיךָ:  וְקַמְתָּ וְעָלִיתָ--אֶל-הַמָּקוֹם, אֲשֶׁר יִבְחַר יְהוָה אֱלֹהֶיךָ בּוֹ.
>    וּבָאתָ, אֶל-הַכֹּהֲנִים הַלְוִיִּם, וְאֶל-הַשֹּׁפֵט, אֲשֶׁר יִהְיֶה בַּיָּמִים הָהֵם; וְדָרַשְׁתָּ וְהִגִּידוּ לְךָ, אֵת דְּבַר הַמִּשְׁפָּט.

Are these discernible or in action today in Israel?
Is it possible to bring cases before them in matters of the law?

and on a side note, just out of curiosity,  are these what is alluded to in Proverbs 31:23:

> נוֹדָע בַּשְּׁעָרִים בַּעְלָהּ;    בְּשִׁבְתּוֹ, עִם-זִקְנֵי-אָרֶץ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference is to the Sanhedrin in the Bais Hamikdash which deals with the court cases. Even though we no longer have a temple, a Sanhedrin, or complete authority of the court system, we are still required to follow tha authorities of our day. Rav Hirsch points out that we should appoint "kohanim Leviim" to the court.

> not so much their special character as priests, as their tribal
>   character as Levites, who had proved themselves as undaunted practical
>   representatives of the Torah, a spirit, the constant existence of
>   which is certainly highly desirable to have in the supreme "College of
>   the Torah".

Rav Hirsch points out that *who shall be in those days*

> the Gemora in Rosh Hashana 25a teaches the principle that at all times
>   one has to obey and follow the contemporary ecclesiastical authorities
>   who are qualified by their conscentiousness and their knowledge to be
>   teachers of the Law, even if they do not attain the greatness of mind
>   and spirit of the authorities of the past.

Indeed, even though we do not have the Sanhedrin or the temple, nor does bais din have the authority of the state, we should still treat the batei din and the gedolei hador of our day **as if** they had the authority of those days.